How to configure Hive Metastore Docker container?
I am building a demo for my company, with a setup of:

Trino
MinIO
Hive Metastore (HMS)

Trino should use HMS as Iceberg catalog, and the data and metadata should be stored in MinIO.
Now, after including all the necessary jars to make HMS work with MinIO, I get the error when creating a simple schema in the Iceberg catalog
Failed to create external path s3a://warehouse/ for database warehouse. This may result in access not being allowed if the StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider is enabled: null

I don't know why HMS wants to access MinIO. I don't see the point for it to access MinIO. Regardless, I tried to provide hive-site.xml and core-site.xml for it. I have no idea if my setting is taking effect, because when if I specified some wrong configurations, there were no errors.
<configuration>
    <!-- hive-site.xml -->
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>s3a://warehouse/</value>
        <description>Location of the default database for the warehouse</description>
    </property>
</configuration>

<configuration>
    <!-- core-site.xml -->
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>minioadmin</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>minioadmin</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.endpoint</name>
        <value>http://minio:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.path.style.access</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

I setup Hive in compose as follow:
# In docker-compose.yaml
hms:
    image: docker.io/apache/hive:4.0.0
    ports:
      - 9083:9803
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: metastore
      HIVE_CUSTOM_CONF_DIR: /custom-conf
    volumes:
      - ./hive/:/custom-conf/
      ...and other jars

For completeness, here is my Trino catalog config
connector.name=iceberg

hive.metastore.uri=thrift://hms:9083

fs.native-s3.enabled=true
s3.region=eu-north-1
s3.endpoint=http://minio:9000
s3.path-style-access=true
s3.aws-access-key=minioadmin
s3.aws-secret-key=minioadmin

I wish that you can help me figure out 2 things:

Is this the correct way to specify configurations for HMS?
How can I configure HMS as a catalog for Iceberg that Trino can use?

Many thanks!

HMS needs to create a subdirectory under the directory defined by “hive.metastore.warehouse.dir” for the table you are creating. It is suggested to pre-create “hive.metastore.warehouse.dir”. In Hive, you can specify a different directory for your table, “create table foo(i int) location “/my-other-directory”,  but I am not sure if you can do it from Trino.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#:~:text=In%20addition%2C%20you%20must%20use%20below%20HDFS%20commands%20to%20create%20/tmp%20and%20/user/hive/warehouse%20(aka%20hive.metastore.warehouse.dir)%20and%20set%20them%20chmod%20g%2Bw%C2%A0before%20you%20can%20create%20a%20table%20in%20Hive.

I had the same problem using the official hive image apache/hive and following this official guide https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Storage+Based+Authorization+in+the+Metastore+Server I mounted the hive-site.xml file on path /opt/hive/conf/hive-site.xml and added this lines of code:
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.pre.event.listeners</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.AuthorizationPreEventListener</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider</value>
    </property>


Restarting the container the problem was resolved
